# Replace multiple ranges in a string

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to replace multiple ranges in a string, e.g.:

```
Original string: "My XXX XXX is Y"
Range 1: Start=3, Length=3, Replacement=house
Range 2: Start=14, Length=1, Replacement=big

Desired output: "My house XXX is big"
```

How to do that with .NET and C#? I tried to replace one range at a time, however, this ruins the indices if the replacement string has a different length than its range. **I only know of the indices** and **replaced strings in ranges are not unique**.  Do I really have to manually update all those indices all the time or is there a built-in way to do that?

Comment: Any reason you are replacing by checking indices instead of string contents (regex) ?

Comment: Dirtiest solution would be to start from the *end*. That's why you loops that delete elements from lists start from the end and count down to 0. That said, a Regex is a better option than fragile indexes *and* doesn't create temporary strings

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Yes, I only know of the indices + contents may be multiple times within the file (they are not as nicely marked like "XXX", they are more like random indices).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Uh, that sounds not too bad. I'll try that!

Comment: It's not a neat little utility function, but you could use a StringBuilder to concatenate a bunch of substrings together.  You'd have to write the looping/replacement rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please perform replacements starting from the last index - from right-most string to left-most. Now you don't need to update any indices. It's that easy.

Comment: Thank you, PanagiotisKanavos already hinted the solution. I'll give him/her two days to collect the reputation by answering the question. If he/she does not answer the question you are next in line ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be build the result piece by piece into a `StringBuilder`. That way, you have the original string at hand the whole time, so you can use the original indexes:

```
static string ReplaceRanges(string original, IEnumerable<Range> ranges)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder(original.Length);

    int index = 0;

    foreach (var range in ranges)
    {
        result.Append(original, index, range.Start - index);

        result.Append(range.Replacement);

        index = range.Start + range.Length;
    }

    result.Append(original, index, original.Length - index);

    return result.ToString();
}
```

A slight modification of this approach would be to precompute the length of the final string based on the ranges. This would minimize unnecessary allocations, which could be important if you have many ranges.